# How do I find transformation matrix T?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given is the coordinate transformation

$x_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_1'+x_2')$

$x_2=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x_1'-x_2')$

who through the following equations
**a)** $x^2_1 - 2x_1x_2 + x_2^2= 9$  **b)**$x^2_1 +x_1x_2 + x_2^2= 3$ described curves.

How do I find  transformation matrix T ? What are the equations in the new coordinates? What kind of curves is it? Sketch the curves in the new and in the old coordinate?

Answer (score 2):

First of all: You can directly read the matrix from the given equatiosn:

$$\begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \end{pmatrix} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1' \\ x_2' \end{pmatrix}$$

Finding the new equations is just a matter of plugging these substitutions in your old equations. For example for equatin $(a)$ you'll get:

$$9 = \frac{1}{2}(x_1'+x_2')^2-(x_1'+x_2')(x_1'-x_2')+\frac{1}{2}(x_1'-x_2')^2$$

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand how to find transformation matrix? How to see what kind od curve it is ....

Comment: The matrix equation is just your linear equations rewritten as a matrix equation!

Comment: Oh, in case you do not have those given, this is called PCA (principal component analysis) and can easily be done e.g. via singular value decomposition, which is a general method for analyzing quadratic forms.

Comment: I really don't understand. Can you show mw how to find transformaiton matrix?

Comment: Ok, do you know how to transform a system of linear equations into a matrix equation?

Comment: Yes, but how did  you hat that matrix $\begin{pmatrix}
1 &1 \\ 
 1&-1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: oh sorry i get it

Comment: so our T will be that * $1/sqrt(2)$

Comment: But how do I see what kind of curve it is?

Comment: For that, please make sure you read about conic sections: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section